# Wine: Company Of Heroes - Tales Of Valor GameInst.exe Encountered A Serious Problem

Tags: 16.04, wine, winetricks

I am trying to install Company Of Heroes - Tales Of Valor on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using `wine-2.0-rc3` and I am encountering this error:

[image]

I have installed `d3dx9`, `d3dx10`, `vcrun2005`, and `vcrun2008` via `winetricks`, and tried using Windows XP and Windows 7 compatibility mode on `winecfg`, but to no avail. I am wondering if this is some compatibility issue on my version of `wine`, because I tried installing Company Of Heroes via `PlayOnLinux` and it is trying to download `wine 1.5`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be problem with wine version, try installing with another version of wine, on WineHQ appdb Company Of Heroes has ranking platinum and everything is working with wine version 1.9.15. Maybe PlayOnLinux is doing right when installing wine 1.5.

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you ASAP. :)

Comment: I installed `wine 1.6.2` which tags the game as Platinum at WineHQ appdb, but issue persists.